# How does java.sql.Date work with negative dates?

Tags: java, date, time, long-integer

I had a situation where the Java runtime returned sort of "inverted" millisecond values when reading dates from the database (in `java.sql.Date`). The millisecond value was approximately the same amount of days, but counted backwards from year 0.

The problem was solved by just restarting the Java runtime.

But: I found out that Java handles these "inverted" values almost correctly except of the week day.

When you run the following code:

```
System.out.println(new java.util.Date(253402214400000l));
System.out.println(new java.util.Date(-377648784000000l));
```

You will get the following output:

```
Fri Dec 31 01:00:00 CET 9999
Tue Dec 31 01:00:00 CET 9999
```

Another example:

```
System.out.println(new java.util.Date(-294192000000l));
System.out.println(new java.util.Date(-123967324800000l));
```

Result:

```
Mon Sep 05 01:00:00 CET 1960
Mon Sep 05 01:00:00 CET 1960
```

When using online converters, the result will be different for the particular second line. It will result in a negative date (the year is negative) close to the real, positive date:

```
Example1:
253402214400000 = Fri Dec 31 9999 01:00:00
-377648784000000 = Tue Oct 15 -9998 02:00:00

Example 2:
-294192000000 = Mon Sep 05 1960 02:00:00
-123967324800000 = Mon Aug 19 -1959 02:00:00
```

I have not found any information about this "topic".

So, what's the myth behind "inverted" dates? Why does Java handle them almost correctly? And what is the sense of a JDBC `ResultSet` returning "inverted" millisecond values when calling `resultSet.getDate(1).getTime()`?

Comment: Are you talking about `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`? Realise that behavior of a JDBC result set is driver specific, as each driver implements it for their specific database.

Comment: It's a java.sql.Date (subclass of java.util.Date)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "inverted".

Comment: By "inverted", I mean that - if the database contained a date within 1960, I received a millisecond value that corresponds to a date in -1959, or 9999 was received as -9998. So, comparing validFrom/validTo-Dates, the validFrom-Dates were larger than the validTo-Dates, as the millisecond value has been inverted. 253402214400000 was returned as -377648784000000, which, when converted to a Java date, leads exactly to the same date, but using online converters, leads to the same date before year 0.

Comment: `java.sql.Date` is not really a good one to use for reasoning about dates in Java in general, for one the `toString` implementation of `java.sql.Date` prints years of 4 digits only.

Comment: Sorry, in my examples above I was working with java.util.Date. But JDBC ResultSet returns java.sql.Date.

Answer (score 1):

When you are passing a negative number in the Date constructor then it is considered as number of milleseconds before 1/1/1970. The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#setTime(long) says:

> date - milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT not to exceed
>   the milliseconds representation for the year 8099. **A negative number
>   indicates the number of milliseconds before January 1, 1970,**

You can see the result which you get when you try to provide the `Long.MIN_VALUE` and `Long.MAX_VALUE` in the Date constructor.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy G, HH:mm:ss.S Z");
System.out.println(df.format(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)));
System.out.println(df.format(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE)));
```

**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/fzEOm5)**

Comment: how does this answer a question?

Comment: Thanks, I know. The question was not about negative millisecond values before year 1970, but about inverted millisecond values before year 0.

Answer (score 1):

> I found out that Java handles these "inverted" values almost correctly except of the week day.

In your first example, the two dates are not the same - one is BC and the other one AD (which explains why the day of the week is different):

```
Date d1 = new Date(253402214400000l);
Date d2 = new Date(-377648784000000l);
DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy G");
System.out.println(fmt.format(d1)); //9999 AD
System.out.println(fmt.format(d2)); //9999 BC
```

So your observation is just a coincidence (however there may be a date formatter somewhere that has gone wild and negates the years or the years may actually be negative in your database).

The difference with online converters is probably due to how the year 0 is taken into account and/or variations in the calendar used for the calculations.

Comment: But a restart of the Java runtime solved the problem :-) so no wrong values in the database, no special date formatters in use.

Comment: @praisezh Can you find a way to reproduce the problem?