# How to convert date string "/Date( -62135575200000-0600)/"

Tags: android, json, date, simpledateformat

One of the attributes in `JSON` have date value **("/Date( -62135575200000-0600)/")**, I'm not familiar with the type. How to convert this string to `SimpleDateFormat`

**JSON attribute:**

```
"toDate": "/Date( -62135575200000-0600)/"
```

Comment: Is it a third party JSON object or are you creating this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
String date = "-62135575200000-0600"; // strip down the numerical value 
Date date1 = new Date(date);
DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy mm dd");
System.out.println(fmt.format(date1));
```

Negative date is taken as milliseconds before 1970 jan 1.
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178106/how-does-java-sql-date-work-with-negative-dates)

Comment: getting an error:- java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "62135575200000"